# Oracle EE 11.2g: how to generate fresh new redo logs

Tags: oracle, database-administration, data-recovery

In the company I work for we are heavy users of VMware machines. Almost all our projects are developed inside a virtual environment up to the point where we have to deploy them into a production system.

While in development, some colleagues of mine deleted the redo log files for Oracle in the hopes of gaining some free space. Now they are unable to start the database instance. Is there a way of generating a fresh new redo log so that the instance can be started?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of redo logs, online and archive. You can restart without the archived ones. The online ones are a different matter. You need to use the RESETLOGS option

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/backup.102/b14191/osrecov009.htm

Comment: It seems my colleagues tried using the RESETLOGS option but with no luck. Thanks for your help nonetheless.